# Random Internal 500 server error

Tags: java, apache, internal

I am getting a random Internal 500 server error, in the production environment.

We tried to replicate the same in the test environment but to no avail.

The error message is shown generally at the end of a webpage, and it dose not occur frequently but once in a while in any page and then it would vanish like it never happened and there are no entries for it in the log files.

We have gone through the code on the pages the error had shown but their was nothing wrong there.

The major problem though are the details that are with the error message like the server info and other details.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Date:Tue,26 Jun 2012 02:33:47 GMT Server:Oracle-Application-Server-10g Last-Modified: Sat. 16 Jun 2012 11:29:47 GMT ETag: "1cb1e-49d-2fed6e2b" Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length:729 Connection:close Content-Type: text/html
```

We tried but were not able to suppress those details from appearing.

It would be great if anyone could tell me the config parameters to be added to block those details from appearing.

And triple great if anyone had faced the same problem and could point to the sol.

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: Check your apache `error.log`

Comment: its too wide question. If error occurs there should be logs

Comment: There weren't any entries for the error message in the log... that is the problem.

Comment: @PaYne is your problem solved? if it is then can you please share your resolution. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.But "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" cause unable to complete the request.[Here](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/http-status-codes/) is the reference to learn server error.If you want to get more rightful answer, support your problem completely (eg .support server log file or code sample).

Comment: Thanks Sai, but the problem is that their is no fixed reason that I could decipher of this error. It would appear randomly at the footer of a page once in a while and next time it would be fine no errors there are no log entries for it too. I am not even replicate the problem its like it will happen only when the server wants it to happen :( .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Filter for supressing the Internal 500 error. I am getting the same error on the production environment. You can use java filter for a paticular page or for whole application. Find out the Internal 500 error in the Java filter from the response which have received in filter and supressed it with the blank.